# Maxmind Geoip2 API vs downloadable database

Tags: ip-address, geoip, maxmind, geoip2

I was wondering the differences between the usage of maxmind downloadable database vs their direct web API. Any particular benefits if I download the maxmind database locally to my server instead of using their direct web API? Is there any accuracy difference between both? Should I update the maxmind GeoIP2 database, very frequently to get accuracy? What is the best option here and why people choose downloadable database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the comparison between database and web service option. It is general comparison and should be applicable to providers such as Maxmind and IP2Location.

**Downloadable Database**

*Pros*

- Low network latency
- Flat fee, No pay-per-use cost

*Cons*

- Periodic database download and updates
- More complex database query or programming libraries

**Web Service**

*Pros*

- No database update or maintenance
- Slightly more accurate in case you missed updates
- Simple API interface

*Cons*

- High network latency / Slow
- Variable fee, pay-per-use basis

Comment: Useful answer, but you have the Pros an Cons for the service backwards,

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the Pros and Cons.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add privacy and the sharing of data with third parties to the pros of setting up your own database. Firefox has been blocking CORS requests to Maxmind services recently and increasingly there are legal hoops to jump through for sharing user web data. If you're running your own database then you don't need to share your users data with Maxmind.